# Use value from one cell to define "coordinates" of another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use the value of one cell, e.g. 3 to specifiy the coordinates of another cell.

This is what I tried:

```
Wert = Range("E22").Value
Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("A1:BWert").Copy
```

Comment: `Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("A1:B" & Wert).Copy`

Comment: ^^ Tip: look into explicit sheet references to prevent unwanted results too =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When cell coordinates are calculated you will find it more expedient to specify cells as `Cells([Row], [Column]) and define a range by its first and last cell. When you employ this syntax your task would be solved like this:-

```
With Sheets("Tabelle2")
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Wert, 2)).Copy
End With
```

The variation below is equivalent and perhaps easier to read for a beginner. However it is logically inconsistent because column letters can't be calculated.

```
With Sheets("Tabelle2")
    .Range(.Cells(1, "A), .Cells(Wert, "B")).Copy
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in my actual code and it did copy it however it pasted it from A1 and A1 to like J 1 and J2. heres my entire code: It was supposed to copy the range A1:B10 from Table2 to A1:B10 in Table3.
How could this be done?

````
Option Explicit


Sub Kopieren()
Dim Wert As Integer


Wert = Range("E22").Value


Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("A1:B" & Wert).Copy
Sheets("Tabelle3").Range("A1:B" & Wert).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True





End Sub```
````

Comment: Found out how: `Sheets("Tabelle3").Range("A1:B" & Wert).PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme`